# How to open an os app with python without direction?

Tags: python, operating-system, direction

I have been having a problem with opening programes with python. I've been using `os.system("file")` and `os.startfile("file")`, but the problem is, that it uses **direction** of the app, and when this code goes to the other computer, the direction is not the same, as on my computer. Is it possible to open an app without writing its direction just by a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `subprocess.call` is what you're looking for (assuming the path to the executable is in your global $PATH variable).

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about that, please?

Comment: @Resadesker https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. This module allows to launch subprocesses from your program. With `call` you could launch the command of the program you want to open. For example, if I wanted to open Firefox from my program I would simply use `subprocess.call(['firefox', arg1, arg2, ...])`.